# How to only list the child terms of a taxonomy and not their parents?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm creating an age select menu in the admin, populated from a taxonomy of `age`. The taxonomy is hierarchical as follows:

- 18-25 (parent, ID 183)

  - 18 (child)
  - 19
  - 20
  - 21
  - 22
  - 23
  - 24
  - 25
- 26-30 (parent, ID 184)

  - 26
  - 27
  - 28
  - 29
  - 30

I would like to only list the children (18, 19 etc) and not the parents (18-25, 26-30) etc. Currently I am using `get_terms` with the `parent` argument, but it doesn't accept more than 1 parent ID. Here's what I have so far, which shows the children from 18-25.

```
    $ages = get_terms( 'age', array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => '183',
    ));
```

Here's what I want it to do, but isn't supported. I have also tried it with an array but it doesn't work either.

```
    $ages = get_terms( 'age', array(
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'parent' => '183,184',
    ));
```

I see there is a [get_term_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) function but I'm unsure of how to use this either as it looks like it only accepts one value also. Eg:
In this example it would build an unordered list but I could modify for select menu.

```
<?php
    $termID = 183;
    $taxonomyName = "age";
    $termchildren = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($termchildren as $child) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomyName );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term->name, $taxonomyName ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: Call `get_terms` twice and merge the two arrays of results?

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I thought of doing it this way, but even if I merge the ID's into an array, I can't see how it would work because it would be the same as listing them manually - 183, 184, which doesn't work.

Comment: Having read the accepted answer i now realise your question wasn't entirely clear, from the looks of things you wanted *all* terms, excluding top level ones.. (which you can do with a single `get_terms` call). Your question read as if you were wanting all children of 2 particular parent terms..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$taxonomyName = "age";
//This gets top layer terms only.  This is done by setting parent to 0.
$parent_terms = get_terms(
  $taxonomyName,
  array(
    'parent' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'slug',
    'hide_empty' => false
  )
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $parent_terms as $pterm ) {
  //Get the Child terms
  $terms = get_terms(
    $taxonomyName,
    array(
      'parent' => $pterm->term_id,
      'orderby' => 'slug',
      'hide_empty' => false
    )
  );
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link($term) . '">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks @Manny, worked a treat. I took what you provided and mashed it into the select menu I was after. Great stuff.

Comment: No problem.  Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: See **karimhossenbux**'s answer below for a much more efficient answer.

Comment: `$term->name` is invalid in `get_term_link()`, it only accepts the term ID, slug or object

Answer (score 17):

You could also do:

```
$terms = get_terms($taxonomyName);
foreach($terms as $term) {
    if ($term->parent != 0) { // avoid parent categories
        //your instructions here
    }
}
```

I've noted that parent have "parent" field equal to 0, and a child have his parent id in it.

Comment: The accepted answer runs N get_terms() calls and runs in polynomial time. This answer runs a single get_terms() call and runs in linear time. **This is a much better answer.**

Comment: @dotancohen You can do this without having to exclude top level terms on output, you can remove top level terms with the `wpse_exclude_top` parameter added to the query arguments ;-). I do however agree, this is faster than the accepted answer

Comment: @PieterGoosen: Thank you Pieter. I just grepped the 4.4.2 source code for the strings `wpse_exclude_top` and `exclude_top` but did not find them. Nor does [google](http://google.com/search?q=wpse_exclude_top) know about that. Where is it documented?

Comment: @dotancohen in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 6):

We can exclude the top level parents by filtering them out by using the [`terms_clauses`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/terms_clauses/) filter to alter the SQL query before it executes. This way we do not need to skip parents in the final `foreach` loop as they are not in the returned array of terms, this saves us unnecessary work and coding

You can try the following:

```
add_filter( 'terms_clauses', function (  $pieces, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    // Check if our custom arguments is set and set to 1, if not bail
    if (    !isset( $args['wpse_exclude_top'] ) 
         || 1 !== $args['wpse_exclude_top']
    )
        return $pieces;

    // Everything checks out, lets remove parents
    $pieces['where'] .= ' AND tt.parent > 0';

    return $pieces;
}, 10, 3 );
```

To exclude top level parents, we can now pass `'wpse_exclude_top' => 1` with our array of arguments. The new `wpse_exclude_top` parameter is supported by the filter above

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category', ['wpse_exclude_top' => 1] );
if (    $terms
     && !is_wp_error( $terms )
) {
    echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';  
        }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Just a note, [`get_term_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) do no not accept the term name, only, slug, ID or the complete term object. For performance, always always pass the term object to `get_term_link()` if the term object is available (*as in this case*)

Comment: Hi, any idea how to solve this one? stackoverflow.com/q/70327174/9036446

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just set the `childless` argument to true?

```
$ages = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'age',
    'childless' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: setting the ```childless``` argument to true means you can only go 1 level deep, so this doesn't work for taxonomies with 3 or more levels.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs! Thank you!

Comment: Also it will return **parents without children** instead of **children without parents**.

Answer (score -1):

If you display multiple parent's child, you can try this. Display mention term ids child term.

```
$termIds = array(367, 366, 365, 364, 363, 362);
$taxonomyName = "age";

$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'term_id', 
    'order'             => 'DESC',                      
    'hide_empty'        => false,                       
    'childless'         => false,
); 

$terms = get_terms( $taxonomyName, $args );

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
$inc = 1;
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {                           
 if (in_array($term->parent, $termIds)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$term->term_id.'"><font><font>'.$term->name.'</font></font></option>';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you think this code should work. Also, I am pretty sure that a hard-coded solution is not the best way.

Comment: Question mentions with ids, for this reason I have answered related think.