# Get the Term List - Ordering

Tags: terms

I have a country taxonomy with children taxonomies > state & city.

For a given entry for a restaurant in Nantucket, I want it to say "Nantucket, Massachusetts, United States (each linked to those taxonomy pages)", but the code I have gotten to work (I'm new to PHP) outputs:

Massachusetts, Nantucket, United States

```
$terms_as_text = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'country', '', ', ', '' ) ; 
echo strip_tags($terms_as_text);
```

How to I get this to order by the reverse hierarchical order of the taxonomy > City, State, Country?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37285/custom-taxonomy-get-the-terms-listing-in-order-of-parent-child?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment above, you would replace your code with something like this:

```
print_taxonomy_ranks( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'post_tags' ) );
```

and in your function `print_taxonomy_ranks` you'd replace the echo statement with your preferred output.

```
function print_taxonomy_ranks( $terms ) {
// if terms is not array or its empty don't proceed
if ( ! is_array( $terms ) || empty( $terms ) ) {
    return false;
}

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    // if the term have a parent, set the child term as attribute in parent term
    if ( $term->parent != 0 )  {
        $terms[$term->parent]->child = $term;   
    } else {
        // record the parent term
        $parent = $term;
    }
}

echo "Order: $parent->name, Family: {$parent->child->name}, Sub-Family: {$parent->child->child->name}";
}
```

Extracted from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37285/custom-taxonomy-get-the-terms-listing-in-order-of-parent-child?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```
     <?php

            /**
             * Retrieve a post's terms as a list ordered by hierarchy.
             *
             * @param int $post_id Post ID.
             * @param string $taxonomy Taxonomy name.
             * @param string $term_divider Optional. Separate items using this.
             * @param string $reverse Optional. Reverse order of links in string.
             * @return string
             */
            class GetTheTermList {

                public function get_the_term_list($post_id, $taxonomy, $term_divider = '/', $reverse = false) {
                    $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post_id, $taxonomy);
                    $parents_assembled_array = array();
                    //***
                    if (!empty($object_terms)) {
                        foreach ($object_terms as $term) {
                            $parents_assembled_array[$term->parent][] = $term;
                        }
                    }
                    //***
                    $sorting_array = $this->sort_taxonomies_by_parents($parents_assembled_array);
                    $term_list = $this->get_the_term_list_links($taxonomy, $sorting_array);
                    if ($reverse) {
                        $term_list = array_reverse($term_list);
                    }
                    $result = implode($term_divider, $term_list);

                    return $result;
                }

                private function sort_taxonomies_by_parents($data, $parent_id = 0) {
                    if (isset($data[$parent_id])) {
                        if (!empty($data[$parent_id])) {
                            foreach ($data[$parent_id] as $key => $taxonomy_object) {
                                if (isset($data[$taxonomy_object->term_id])) {
                                    $data[$parent_id][$key]->childs = $this->sort_taxonomies_by_parents($data, $taxonomy_object->term_id);
                                }
                            }

                            return $data[$parent_id];
                        }
                    }

                    return array();
                }

                //only for taxonomies. returns array of term links
                private function get_the_term_list_links($taxonomy, $data, $result = array()) {
                    if (!empty($data)) {
                        foreach ($data as $term) {
                            $result[] = '<a rel="tag" href="' . get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                            if (!empty($term->childs)) {
                                //***
                                $res = $this->get_the_term_list_links($taxonomy, $term->childs, array());
                                if (!empty($res)) {
                                    //***
                                    foreach ($res as $val) {
                                        if (!is_array($val)) {
                                            $result[] = $val;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //***
                                }
                                //***
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return $result;
                }

            }
            ?>

    <?php
    //EXAMPLE OF USING

        $term_list_object = new GetTheTermList();
        $car_location = $term_list_object->get_the_term_list($post_id, 'carlocation', '-',TRUE);

        ?>
```