# Order get_terms() by hierarchy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I am trying to query a custom taxonomy terms in a way that keeps the hierarchical structure.

Here is the code that I am using..

```
function ev_test_data() {
    $title = 'Mens Levi\'s Jeans';
    $titles = str_replace( array("'", '"', '-', '\\' ), '', explode( ' ', trim($title)) );
    $cats = array();
    foreach ( $titles as $kw ) {
        $terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'orderby' => 'parent', // I guess this is where I am lost.
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'name__like' => $kw,
        ) );
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $cats[] = $term->term_id;
        }
    }

    $finals = array();
    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        $catobj = get_term_by( 'id', $cat, 'product_cat' );
        $tree = '';
        $ancentors = array_reverse(get_ancestors( $cat, 'product_cat', 'taxonomy' ), true);
        $i=1;
        foreach ( $ancentors as $ancentor ) {
            $sterm = get_term_by( 'id', $ancentor, 'product_cat' );
            $tree .= $i == 1 ? '<b>' . $sterm->name . '</b>' : ' > ' . $sterm->name;
            $i++;
        }
        $tree .= ' > ' . $catobj->name;
        $finals[$cat] = $tree;
    }

    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $finals, true ) . '</pre>'; 
}
```

This produces this list.

```
Array
(
    [4638] => Fashion > Womens Clothing
    [4699] => Fashion > Womens Handbags & Bags
    [4709] => Fashion > Womens Shoes
    [4461] => Fashion > Mens Accessories
    [4493] => Fashion > Mens Clothing
    [4512] => Fashion > Mens Shoes
    [4603] => Fashion > Womens Accessories
    [4779] => Fashion > Vintage > Mens Vintage Clothing
    [4821] => Fashion > Vintage > Womens Vintage Clothing
    [4290] => Fashion > Kids Clothing, Shoes & Accs > Boys Clothing (Sizes 4 & Up) > Jeans
    [4319] => Fashion > Kids Clothing, Shoes & Accs > Girls Clothing (Sizes 4 & Up) > Jeans
    [4354] => Fashion > Kids Clothing, Shoes & Accs > Unisex Clothing > Jeans
    [4500] => Fashion > Mens Clothing > Jeans
    [4660] => Fashion > Womens Clothing > Jeans
    [4666] => Fashion > Womens Clothing > Maternity > Jeans
)
```

However, this list is not ordered as I want. I need it to be ordered by the hierarchical order. Something like this.

```
Array
(
    [4493] => Fashion > Mens Clothing
    [4500] => Fashion > Mens Clothing > Jeans
    [4638] => Fashion > Womens Clothing
    [4660] => Fashion > Womens Clothing > Jeans
    [4666] => Fashion > Womens Clothing > Maternity > Jeans
    [4699] => Fashion > Womens Handbags & Bags
    [4709] => Fashion > Womens Shoes
    [4603] => Fashion > Womens Accessories
    [4512] => Fashion > Mens Shoes
    [4461] => Fashion > Mens Accessories
    [4779] => Fashion > Vintage > Mens Vintage Clothing
    [4821] => Fashion > Vintage > Womens Vintage Clothing
    [4290] => Fashion > Kids Clothing, Shoes & Accs > Boys Clothing (Sizes 4 & Up) > Jeans
    [4319] => Fashion > Kids Clothing, Shoes & Accs > Girls Clothing (Sizes 4 & Up) > Jeans
    [4354] => Fashion > Kids Clothing, Shoes & Accs > Unisex Clothing > Jeans

)
```

Can this be done using WordPress built in functions? If not, what would be the logic for the custom query? I am not asking to do it for me, but any help or guide or headstart would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing and think this should work for you : [Custom taxonomy, get_the_terms, listing in order of parent > child](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37285/custom-taxonomy-get-the-terms-listing-in-order-of-parent-child)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_list_categories](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/#Display_Terms_in_a_custom_taxonomy) taxonomy argument which has built in support for hierarchal lists.

Comment: Thank you for stopping by. `wp_list_categories()` can not exactly be used to **query** for terms I need.